# Override WSDL returned via ?wsdl in JAX-WS

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws, customization

Can I override WSDL being returned by `?wsdl`?

Looks like `wsdlLocation` can serve the purpose. According to multiple examples, I can write something like `WEB-INF/wsdl/DSystemWS.wsdl`. It simply doesn't work. I have tried relative path and absolute paths. The only thing I always get is something like:

> Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.ws.server.ServerRtException: [failed to localize] cannot.load.wsdl(/my/absolute/path/myservice.wsdl)

What's wrong?

Comment: I might be wrong, but experience tells me this is application container specific. This works in JBoss: WSDL under WEB-INF/wsdl directory and @WebService(wsdlLocation="MyService.wsdl") without directory names.

Comment: I use embedded variant and publish my service via `Endpoint.publish(address, implementor);`